# Factorizing a Polynomial over the Integers

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, factoring

What are the most efficient algorithms to factorize a polynomial over integers, knowing that it has only integer roots? I googled around a lot, but most of the work seems to be around Finite fields. Is general factorization NP-hard?

Related question: Suppose I had a Polynomial $H = P + X$, where I knew $H$. I also know $X$ is a natural number, and that $P$ only had integral roots. I get infinite tries at $X$, and every time I guess, I know whether I'm right or wrong. Let's assume for the sake of argument I know that $X$ is from $\{0,1,2,\dotsc,N\}$. Could I improve my guessing of $X$ from knowing $H$ and that $P$ has only integral roots, over randomly guessing new elements from the set $\{0,1,2,\dotsc,N\}$?

Comment: [Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: But how much would the improvement really be ? We would be able to run some checks per value and see we don't want to try it, but would it be computationally worth it over just trying every value ? Remember, I don't know the roots of P, only that P has all roots in Z.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the related question.  Are $H$ and $P$ polynomials each with integer roots?

Comment: No, H merely has integral coefficients. Its roots need not be integral.

Comment: So $H$ is a polynomial (known) with integer coefficients and you want to find a shift $X$ so that $H-X$ is a polynomial with only integer roots?  How do you know such a shift exists at all?  Is it just given by hypothesis?

Comment: Let's assume I know that.

Comment: When you say that $P$ has only integer roots, to you mean it has no roots in $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb Z$, or merely that it has no roots in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z$?

Comment: Gaussian integers would make an interesting side problem but I would like to focus on the reals. Although approaches from that angle are welcome as well.

Comment: @user243554: Is that supposed to answer my question? For example, I still don't know whether $(x-1)(x^2+2)$ is a possible $P$. Its single _real_ root is integral, but it has complex roots that aren't.

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant Polynomials with complex roots that were gaussian integers. No, I am not counting that. All the roots of P are real and integral.